# Компоновка Qt, как не изменять размеры окна по Layout, лежащему на нем

Tags: c++, qt

Как в Qt, используя компоновку (например, QGridLayout), запретить подстраиваться MainWindow под потомков, лежащих в QGridLayout? То есть необходимо разрешить потомкам быть за границей MainWindow вне видимости?

Answer (score 1):

В окно поместите `QScrollArea`, а в него уже в layout всё, что нужно.